# Add animation to bootstrap-treeview plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, treeview, bootstrap-treeview

I'm using this plugin [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) and its working great but one thing that its missing is animation when expand / collapse the parent nodes.

Can anyone direct me on how I can add the animation for this nice plugin?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/jhfrench/bootstrap-tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work, as the code is written in away that doesn't support animation.
What I suggest is to use another tree plugin, such as this one:
http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs3_ng120_test_page.html

or

http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Nice-Tree-View-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3-Easy-Tree.html

Both supports jquery and bootstrap.

Good luck.